# Log into local Windows 2019 Remote Desktop Server with Azure AD account?

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019, entra-id

Is there a way to use Azure AD accounts to log into a Windows 2019 Remote Desktop Server? (not hosted in an Azure cloud VM)

The idea is to have the user's primary account be the Azure AD account. This would allow them to change passwords online if needed. Then they could use the one account to log into the Remote Desktop as well.

I've seen lots of AD syncing things with hybrid setup that seem to be one way sync from the local to Azure AD, but I'm looking for the other way around - Azure AD is the primary that sends changes to the local AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you gotta use the sync unfortunately, the start of authority will always be the local AD.

There's a new easier sync tool that was recently released to replace Azure AD Connect, called "Azure AD Cloud Sync", check it out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/what-is-cloud-sync

Comment: Thanks Noor. Sounds like we are stuck in the stone age of old Local Active Directory - was really hoping to "upgrade" to better cloud management of the accounts.

Comment: Well, if your plan is to be cloud first, then you could host your servers in Azure and use the "Sign in to Windows virtual machine in Azure using Azure Active Directory authentication" preview feature: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows